# instantiating a generic class data type known at runtime

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I have  a generic class in C# which has 2 data types `public class ResolvedChainSubscriber < K, V>`, now I have to create an instance of this class, but the data type of one of the arguments will only be known at runtime. I have it stored as "Type Prototype"

```
public static Object SubsciberTopic(Type ProtoType, Object obj)
{
    Type[] type={Type.GetType("System.String"),ProtoType};
    Type resolve = typeof(ResolvedChainSubscriber <,>).MakeGenericType(type); 
    Object obj1=Activator.CreateInstance(resolve);
     //now i want to typecast the parameter obj and store it in the new variable obj1
    obj1=(some statement here)obj;


}
```

Comment: Re: "This doesn't seem to be working", please be more specific. *How* does it not work? What result does this produce, and what did you expect instead?

Comment: Re: `Type.GetType("System.String")`, you can simplify this to `typeof(string)`.

Comment: `ResolvedChainSubscriber<string, Activator.CreateInstance(resolve)>` is silly - the generic type arguments have to be known at compile-time, and they have to be types. You already have the type you want in `resolve`, so just do `Activator.CreateInstance(resolve)` - that gives you an instance of the given type. It sounds like you have some big misunderstandings of how generics work - what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: So, i used  Object obj1 = Activator.CreateInstance(resolve); But i get the following exception: MissingMethodException : No parameterless constructor defined for this object.